# get the comment of the materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

good evening,

which is the table or the select I need to get the comment of a materialized view

the comment adds it like this:

```
comment on MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST33 is 'hello';
```

try with:

```
SELECT t.table_name, t.comments FROM USER_TAB_COMMENTS t WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST33';


SELECT * FROM USER_MVIEWS
```

I cannot locate the table where this information is stored.

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Comments on Materialized view:`USER_MVIEW_COMMENTS`, for comments on columns in MV: `USER_COL_COMMENTS`

```
--Comments on Materialized view
SQL>SELECT * FROM user_mview_comments
WHERE mview_name='CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV'

MVIEW_NAME           COMMENTS
-------------------- --------------------
CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV   Monthly total sales




--comments on columns in MV
  SQL>SELECT * FROM user_col_comments
  WHERE table_name='CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV'

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME          COMMENTS             ORIGIN_CON_ID
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------
CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV   CALENDAR_MONTH_DESC  Monthly Calender                 3
CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV   DOLLARS              Monthly Total                    3
```

Links:

[USER_COL_COMMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1036.htm#REFRN20040)

[USER_MVIEW_COMMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5324.htm#REFRN26341)

p.s:-Tested on 19c